# Set "Show Solution Changes" as default view option for Included Changes in VS2013 TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, team-explorer

As the title says, in the view for *Pending Changes*, where VS lists changes in your version, *Show All* is selected by default. In VS2013 update 3, i had this set to *Show Solution Changes* by default.

I have to change this view to show only solution changes for every new *check-in*. I want the default to be *Show Solution Changes*.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the difference is...

Comment: Well now my 'Show Solution Changes' isn't even working and is showing a bunch of folders not in the solution including 'packages'. Ugh!

Comment: @user1228 The difference is that Solution Changes only shows files that are added to your existing solution. This won't make a difference in the mode where files are automatically added, but if you manually have to add or removes files it should only show those. Let's say you added a file, didn't check it in then excluded from the solution. Well maybe you still want it in source control - so the 'Show All' should show that. But I imagine in most people's experience the 'Show All' just contains a bazillion temp files, or otherwise unwanted things that you don't have time to manually delete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I tested, this default setting is controlled by the following registry entry. If the value of this registry entry is set as 1, then it should change the default behavior to filter by "Solution Changes".

**"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl"**

Name:  **FilterPendingChanges**
REG_DWORD

Value: 1 = Show Solution Changes

Value: 0 = Show All

Since we are on this topic, if you want to change the default file listing to "List View" instead of the "Tree View", you should modify the below Registry entry:

**"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\PendingCheckins"**

Name:  **ListLayout**
REG_DWORD

Value: 1 = TreeView

Value: 2 = ListView

Comment: In my testing, Visual Studio sets the value back to 0 at the beginning of every new check in.

Comment: Well I tried that again, but my registry values were retained.

Comment: Tried it again after a fresh boot and having it set to 1 before starting Visual Studio. It nevertheless reverted to “Show All,” and refreshing the registry view showed that Visual Studio again overrode my default. This is quite infuriating.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same **issue** with the **default never "sticking"** *regardless* of what I did in the *UI / Registry*.

I found the problem went away when I **chose to ignore a bunch of changes it kept adding** to the pending changes

These changes happened to be inside the solution's mapped folder (in the NuGet packages folder). These were ignored in my .tfignore file, but had got into TFS's targets before the tfignore file was added.

So guess some code in VS is overriding the user's choice / reg in such cases.

**Solved** by choosing to **Ignore those changes**.

Now it sticks ! Winning !

Answer (score 0):

"Show Solution Changes" will greyed out when your solution is in OFFLINE mode, make sure you turn it ONLINE by following below steps.

[image]