# How to partially undo a TFS checkin across multiple solutions

Tags: tfs, version-control

A while ago, I accidentally checked in some unfinished unittest files I had changed and added in solution A together with some files that contained an actual bugfix for project B.

For some unknown reason I never noticed the checkin was going to include files from another solution so the checkin was done, after which other team members added more checkins to both solutions.

My question now is two-fold;

- How can I undo the part of the checkin that hit solution A without affecting B *at all*
- Is there a way to prevent mistakes like this from ever being possible to happen within Visual Studio (Enterprise 2015), make it impossible to checkin files not part of the currently opened solution somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to use the [ROLLBACK command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd380776.aspx), if you have installed the TFS power tools ([TFPT](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1)) you should be able to do it within visual studio.

1. In your current branch, get the latest version from server then view history and find your changeset. Then right click and select "Rollback entire change set".

[image]

3. This will rollback the changes in your local workspace and checkout the file. (If there are conflicting changes you will have to resolve conflicts.)
4. Now when you are ready to check-in, exclude/undo the files which you don't want to rollback.
5. Commit/checkin the files which you want to rollback.

I haven't seen a better way of doing this, and think that this is much better than individually rolling back each file in the change set.

Now to answer your second question: check this [ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29282225/1766402) which I wrote a while back. I am copying it here for convenience.

As far as I tested, this default setting is controlled by the following registry entry. If the value of this registry entry is set as 1, then it should change the default behavior to filter by "Solution Changes".

**"HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl"**

Name:  **FilterPendingChanges**
REG_DWORD

Value: 1 = Show Solution Changes

Value: 0 = Show All